# Angular ui-router: How to render parent view before child's resolve is resolved?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Consider the following ui-router setup:

**index.html**

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

**ui-router configuration**

```
$stateProvider
  .state('search', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/search',
    views: {
      '@': {
        templateUrl: 'main.html'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('search.results', {
    url: '/results',
    views: {
      ...
    },
    resolve: {
      data: function() {
        ...
      }
    }
  })
```

When I navigate to `search.results`, `main.html` is not rendered until `resolve` is resolved.

Is there a way in ui-router to render the parent view **before** child's `resolve` is resolved?

[Another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22770075/247243)

Comment: The answer is NO. Reason why? state `search.results` is the **one** and **only** state which is in play. While it is built from 2 states *(parent including)* - when navigating to the '/search/results' - only state 'search.results' is triggered... There could be some workarounds... but as written [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) *If any of these dependencies are promises, they will be resolved and converted to a value before the controller is instantiated and the $routeChangeSuccess event is fired*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the purpose of using resolve is to prevent a state change from occurring until the data is loaded.  You obviously don't want that behavior, because you want to enter the state and render part of the view before "data" is loaded.  The solution is to load "data" in the controller instead of using resolve.  If there is logic in the controller that depends on "data," just move that logic into a callback.